# Scrollable resizable table with fixed header

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table, resize

I am looking for a HTML table where the header is fixed. I've found some solutions on the net and on Stack Overflow but none of seems to fit my needs.

What I want is something like this: http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html but when you resize the browser window the table should show a horizontal scrollbar. In the example mentioned above only the browser shows a vertical scrollbar and this is not what I want. If I can adjust the above example or you have something I can use (jQuery is not really an option) then please let me know.

Comment: If you found a pure css solution. Let me know. - Align header and columns without fixed width and without javascript ... I would say impossible.

Comment: would it be possible if i set the columns to a fixed width, e.g. 100px, 200px,...
i think this would also work for me. i optimize it for a specific screen size and if the users cannot see the whole size (cause they have a low resolution like 800x600) they would still be able to scroll the table

Comment: Btw: I recommend to *register* your account to avoid losing the whole account when cleaning the browser cookies and to have the ability to login with the same account at other browsers/computers.

Answer (score 1):

you can use css

ex:

This would add a horizontal and vertical scroll

`table {
 overflow: scroll;
}`

or you can use

overflow-x or overflow-y if you only want one of them.